# Distribute Play! Application With All Dependencies

Tags: apache, playframework-2.0

I am attempting to deploy a Play! Framework application to a server that has no access to the outside world, and only has Apache installed.  Is this possible?  I have looked into all sorts of options, but it would be ideal if I could just package sbt or Play along with my app and just use Apache as a reverse proxy to a self-contained instance of my app, but I haven't found many answers on how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all in the documentation.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionDist

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In your dev machine, from the command line, cd into your app and run `play dist`.   This will create a zip file into the dist directory. Upload that to your server. Then log into your server and unzip it. To start the app run something like this:

```
nohup jdk7/bin/java -Dhttp.port=9000 -cp "mopra/lib/*" play.core.server.NettyServer &
```

replace jsk7/bin/java with your java location, 9000 with the port you'll be forwarding to in apache and "mopra" with the path of what you unzipped.